# AngularJS Concept Understanding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn angular by building this small web app that has this layout:

[image: design]

Simply, the Header's going to say "first app!"
each content nav button is going to be a different category (sports, music, etc) and each one is going to pull some public api and display it in a list on the content page in a table. I think I'm ganna have some search and filtering features and bread crumb if I decide to get fancy and add submenus.

Anyways, I understand the gist of Angular and I went through the phoneCat app tutorial on the angular site: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial and I have been watching bits and pieces of youtube videos on angular as well.

Unfortunately I'm still confused when it comes to transposing the concepts of routing/modules/services/directives/etc... into making an actual web app/site

I'm looking for someone to kind of give me a super high level view of how they would make this app using angular and explain it like I'm a total noob and maybe offer some simple rule of thumb tricks to think about angular in terms of web app components  (eg. when I think of the data in a json file and I want to display it, what could I think of that in terms of angular concepts (data/model/view?) or ie: you'll be using ng-repeat a lot, etc.)

Here are some questions I have off the bat:

1. How many .html files should I have (views?) Do I make a .html for each content page?
2. The Header, Nav and bread crumb (if I use sub menus) will always be displayed to the user. Does this mean I have a index.html page with `<div ng-view></div>` in the body and then have a main.html with the header/nav/breadcrumb, and then have content1.html / content2.html/ content3.html etc separate? If this is true then how do I use more than one ng-view? Or is this where the concept of routing comes in? Could someone explain how I would set up these pages from a ng-view/routing perspective at the simplest level?
3. What does angular.module() do? and when do I use it? I see it at the top of controllers, routing, and services files, etc...
4. Could someone use an example when and how they use a service / factory?

I feel like this is asking a lot for someone to explain. I'm not very computer-sciency minded and I feel stuck in this place where I feel like I can almost build a really cool app but just need to put all the pieces in the right place.

Thanks

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles on this, I want to include a video I found that REALLY helped me understand how to put it all together:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QETUuZ27N0w

Answer (score 1):

Great questions, I know I had my fare share when I first started. I am going to answer each question with a link that will give you detailed information of each.

1. yes, you make a html page for each content page(aka view)
2. Yes, your index page will contain all the static content, and you will use your ng-view directive to  state the area that is dynamic. ng-views are the only way to make set dynamic content. You can use: switches, hide/show, and ng-repeats. For multiple views I would suggest you either user a combination of ng-views and in the views use a switch. If saving the state is very important, than I suggest you look at angular-ui https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
3. Angular.module() is a way to separate/ modularize your code. This means that it is only used in the parts that you explicitly state. When used the dependencies stated will be injected.
4. A great example of how to use the factory module, is in the angularjs tutorial from the official site. I would also suggest some great videos from egghead.io -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvTZbQ_hUZY

If you are looking into a mobile solution, you might want to check out Ionicframework. It is angularjs but with added magic for mobile.

Comment: Thank you, as I was reading your commend I found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QETUuZ27N0w) tut with ui-router (instead of using ng-view) as an excellent tutorial for how angular comes together